# Search Results page destroys background

Tags: javascript, css, search, overflow, contain

Here is the original site. usahvacsupply.com Once you search an item, the search results take over the whole page and kill the background. I'm not sure how to control the overflow. The part of the site where the overflow goes haywire is http://www.usahvacsupply.com/servlet/Categories. I'll post more code if needed. The code on the bottom corresponds with the http://www.usahvacsupply.com/servlet/Categories page. any help would be appreciated.

```
  <table id="body" width="960" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!createBookmark) {
var createBookmark = function() {
if (window.sidebar) // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
window.sidebar.addPanel(document.title, location.href, '');
else if (window.external) // IE Favorite
window.external.AddFavorite(location.href, document.title);
else // all others
alert("Please press CTRL+D to bookmark this page.");
};
}
</script>
<table id="layout" class="panel-layout" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" rules="none">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="p1" valign="top">
<script type="text/javascript">
var ProStores;
if (!ProStores)
ProStores = {};
ProStores.PageLink = function(link) {
var strParams = 's=' + link.getAttribute('page');
var strThis = location.href;
if (strThis.indexOf('?') > -1) {
if (strThis.search(/s=[0-9]+/) > -1)
link.href = strThis.replace(/s=[0-9]+/, strParams);
else
link.href = strThis + '&' + strParams;
}
else
link.href = strThis + '?' + strParams;
};
</script>
<link href="/servlet/0-3-30d-727500-com.prostores.panel.List%7Estyle.css/Asset" title="style" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
<table id="cataloglist.31" class="list-boundary" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" rules="none">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" rules="none">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left" colspan="1">
<h1 align="left">Search Results</h1>
<div class="" align="left" style="padding:2px">
<p>
Found
<b>1000</b>
product(s) for
<b>All</b>
(1-25 of 1000)
</p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="middle" colspan="1">
<div class="product-list-container">
<div class="top">
<div class="right">
<div class="left"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="titlebar group-title">
<b> Breakers  |  Bryant Carrier Payne Day&Night </b>
</div>
<div class="panel-content">
<center>
<table class="" width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="1" style="height:1px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="item-cell" width="100%" valign="bottom" height="100%" style="padding:8px">
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" rules="none">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your problem isn't occuring anymore, but when you search for a product that doesn't exist. Your div.footerBorder gets floated over the background to the left. Fix that by applying:

```
margin-left: 10px;
```

To your

> /servlet/0-0-30d-13e0e1158d0-legacycss/Asset
>   Inside your ".footerBorder" on row 240, replace the whole rule to:

```
.footerBorder {
  width: 960px;
  min-height: 160px;
  background: url("/images/store_version1/footer.gif") no-repeat;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Edit:
If that conflicts on other pages, let me know and I'll help you with it. Cheers!